# Cannot insert russian text into SQL server 2005 db

Tags: asp.net, database, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql, encoding

I'm using stored procedures and DataContext to insert data to SQL Server database (ASP.NET 4 + SQL Server 2005 database, GoDaddy hosting)

But after inserting russian text I see smth like this - '??????'

If I insert constant text I'm using following construction - `N'russian_text'` and it works fine.

Of course, I need to use variables as procedure parameters BUT I can't use it (for example - N@var fails)

ALTHOUGH I'm using N-type fields in tables (`nvarchar` etc.)

Does anybody knows where is mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NVARCHAR variables are declared as

```
DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(100)
SET @var = N'unicode text'
```

and not as DECLARE N@var..., SET N@var

Same applies to procedure and function parameters

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertUnicodeData( @data NVARCHAR(200) ) AS
....
```

Comment: I just needed to refresh procedure in dbml file. Anyway, thanks everyone for help!

Answer (score 1):

your SqlParamter variables in .net need to be of type SqlDbType.NVarChar.
as is now they're SqlDbType.VarChar.
in sql server your @text needs to be nvarchar(ColLength)